# AutoResetEvent inside of WCF process sometimes not waking up thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, synchronization

I'm working on a WCF service that runs some background threads to write data to a database. The background threads are implemented using standard producer & consumer pattern:

```
private readonly Queue<DatabaseChange> ChangeQueue = new Queue<DatabaseChange>();

public Worker(int id)
{
    var workerThread = new Thread(SynchronizationWorker)
    {
        IsBackground = true,
        Name = "deltaQ-" + id,
        Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
    };
    workerThread.Start();
}

private void SynchronizationWorker()
{
    while (true)
    {                  
            s_Logger.Info("waiting for changes...");
            _changeAvailableEvent.WaitOne();

            s_Logger.Info("changes available, start persisting...");
            ...
            // actual work. not important because we never come here (as we can observe in the log file)
    }
}

public void Enqueue(DatabaseChange change)
{
    lock (ChangeQueue)
    {
        ChangeQueue.Enqueue(change);
    }
    _changeAvailableEvent.Set();
}
```

The service runs in single instance mode.

Now what we observe:

the worker threads get started, and everything works fine for a while.

then at some point, even though data is added to the queue and the event set, somehow the worker threads are not waking up anymore.

The worker threads have highest priority as well so even if the server is very busy they should get time slices.

I don't know what to do at this point, it just seems like the IIS host process decides at some point not to schedule the worker threads anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is IIS. IIS worker processes can shut down at any point in time for reasons you cannot control. Also, worker processes can overlap when recycling.

In your case Windows Service would be a better choice.

Check this post for more detail: [WCF hosted in IIS vs in Windows Service](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238566/wcf-service-best-way-to-accept-requests-from-a-client-and-do-background-work)

Comment: the host process is not shut down. the process is still alive, log entries are created from other request. only the worker threads for the database dont run anymore

Comment: Exactly, you cannot abandon a WCF thread. If you start a request, which starts some background workers, then returns, then your worker threads are lost. You have to wait to finish all your background threads before return your WCF response. If you use Windows Service, you can create a Async methods in WCF, which allows you to start background threads and return later... you cannot do that in IIS.

Comment: this doesn't happen with instance context mode single:

Comment: [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]     We have other worker threads as well, and they are running. Only these specific threads for some reason never get scheduled to run.